# Moq with Task await

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, async-await, moq

Since I have converted my WCF methods to Async, my unit tests have failed, and I can't figure out the correct syntax to get them to work.

**Cllient proxy class**

```
 public interface IClientProxy
{
     Task DoSomething(CredentialDataList credentialData, string store);
}
```

**service class**

```
  public class CredentialSync : ICredentialSync
{
    private ICredentialRepository _repository;

    private IClientProxy _client;

    public CredentialSync()
    {
        this._repository = new CredentialRepository();
        this._client = new ClientProxy();
    }

    public CredentialSync(ICredentialRepository repository, IClientProxy client)
    {
        this._repository = repository;
        this._client = client;
    }

   public async Task Synchronise(string payrollNumber)
    {
        try
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(payrollNumber))
            {
                .... some code
              }
            else
            {
                CredentialDataList credentialData = new CredentialDataList();
                List<CredentialData> credentialList = new List<CredentialData>();

                // fetch the record from the database
                List<GetCredentialData_Result> data = this._repository.GetCredentialData(payrollNumber);
                var pinData = this._repository.GetCredentialPinData(payrollNumber);

                // get the stores for this employee
                var storeList = data.Where(a => a.StoreNumber != null)
                    .GroupBy(a => a.StoreNumber)
                    .Select(x => new Store { StoreNumber = x.Key.ToString() }).ToArray();

                var credential = this.ExtractCredentialData(data, pinData, payrollNumber);

                credentialList.Add(credential);
                credentialData.CredentialList = credentialList;

                foreach (var store in storeList)
                {       
                  //this line causes an Object reference not set to an instance of an object error
                   await  _client.DoSomething(credentialData, store.StoreNumber);

                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new FaultException<Exception>(ex);
        }
    }
```

**Test Class**

```
 /// </summary>
[TestClass]
public class SynchTest
{

    private Mock<ICredentialRepository> _mockRepository;
    private Mock<IClientProxy> _mockService;

    [TestInitialize]
    public void Setup()
    {
       ... some setups for repository which work fine
    }

[TestMethod]      
    public async Task SynchroniseData_WithOneEmployee_CallsReplicateService()
    {
        this._mockService = new Mock<IClientProxy>();
        this._mockService.Setup(x=>x.DoSomething(It.IsAny<CredentialDataList>(), It.IsAny<string>()));
        // arrange
        string payrollNumber = "1";
        CredentialSync service = new CredentialSync(this._mockRepository.Object, this._mockService.Object);

        // act
        await service.Synchronise(payrollNumber);

        // assert                 
        this._mockService.VerifyAll();
    }
```

The error is when `ClientProxy.DoSomething` is called:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object

The parameters are both fine.

If I convert my `ClientProxy.DoSomething` method to a synchronous method
(public void `DoSomething(...)` )the code works fine, but I do need this to be called asynchronously

Answer (score 122, accepted):

`DoSomething` returns `null` instead of returning a `Task`, and so you get an exception when awaiting it. You need to specify when building the mock that it should return a `Task`.

In this case it seems that you can simply return an already completed task using `Task.FromResult` so the mock setup should look like this:

```
this._mockService.Setup(...).Returns(Task.FromResult(false));
```

---

Beginning with the next version of .Net (4.6) you can use `Task.CompletedTask` like this:

```
this._mockService.Setup(...).Returns(Task.CompletedTask);
```

Comment: It should be noted in this case, false is just a placeholder, the value false is actually ignored by the mock, it just needs a task, any task, to complete.  It could just as easily be "foo" instead of false...

Comment: @mcse3010 indeed.

Comment: Upvoted for the 4.6 syntax, very concise and indicative of what it actually is.

Answer (score 34):

You can reduce the amount of clutter in the code by using ReturnsAsync

`this._mockService.Setup(...).ReturnsAsync(false)`;

This way you can remove the `Task.FromResult` part of the code

Answer (score 6):

I think you need to return the `Task` from the `DoSomething` mock

```
this._mockService.Setup(x => x.DoSomething(It.IsAny<CredentialDataList>(), It.IsAny<string>()))
    .Returns(Task.FromResult<int>(0));
```

Comment: Or my favorite is `.Returns(Task.Delay(0));`